# Using $A.util.addClass() on Multiple Elements at Once

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is there a way to add `$A.util.addClass()` on multiple elements all at once, or do I always need to declare it for each individual element? For the elements below I want to add or remove a class, is there a way to chain all `addClass()` together?

```
$A.util.addClass(lowercaseDiv, 'slds-hide');
$A.util.addClass(upparcaseDiv, 'slds-hide');
$A.util.addClass(numberDiv, 'slds-hide');
$A.util.addClass(specialCharDiv, 'slds-hide');
$A.util.addClass(minCharDiv, 'slds-hide');
$A.util.removeClass(lowercaseGap, 'slds-hide');
$A.util.removeClass(upparcaseGap, 'slds-hide');
$A.util.removeClass(numberGap, 'slds-hide');
$A.util.removeClass(specialCharGap, 'slds-hide');
$A.util.removeClass(minCharGap, 'slds-hide');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard aura javascript APIs for that. However, you can use below helper function:

HELPER method:

```
processClass : function(elements, process, eclass) {
    if(!Array.isArray(elements))
        elements = [elements];
    if(process==='add')
        elements.forEach(elem=>$A.util.addClass(elem, eclass));
    else if(process==='remove')
        elements.forEach(elem=>$A.util.removeClass(elem, eclass));
    else if(process==='toggle')
        elements.forEach(elem=>$A.util.toggleClass(elem, eclass));
},
```

You can use this as below:

```
let div1 = component.find('div1'),
    div2 = component.find('div2');
helper.processClass([div1,div2],'add','slds-hide');
```

In your use case, you use below:

```
helper.processClass([lowercaseDiv, upparcaseDiv],'add','slds-hide');
// helper.processClass([lowercaseDiv, upparcaseDiv],'remove','slds-hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
['lowercaseDiv','upparcaseDiv','upparcaseDiv','specialCharDiv','minCharDiv'].forEach(function(cmp) => {
 $A.util.addClass(cmp, 'slds-hide');
});
```